# Apex PMD "Validate CRUD permission before SOQL/DML operation" on Lists of Objects

Tags: apex, pmd

I'm trying to clean up my PMD Errors in my code, and I noticed that I'm getting the "Validate CRUD permission before SOQL/DML operation" error when updating a list of a custom object, but not on the individual.

```
public static CustomObject__c updateCustomObject(CustomObject__c customObject) {
    if (CustomObject__c.getSObjectType().getDescribe().isUpdateable() == false) {
        throw new DmlException('No permissions to update.');
    }

    // This is fine with no PMD Error
    update resultObject;
    return resultObject;
}

public static List<CustomObject__c> updateCustomObjects(List<CustomObject__c> customObjects) {
    if (CustomObject__c.getSObjectType().getDescribe().isUpdateable() == false) {
        throw new DmlException('No permissions to update.');
    }

    // Getting PMD Error: Validate CRUD permission before SOQL/DML operation
    update resultObjects;
    return resultObjects;
}
```

The only difference I can see is that one is a List and the other isn't.  Is there a better way to check permissions before updating a list of objects or is this just an issue with PMD and I should ignore it?

Answer (score 0):

That's a bug, it should always prompt you to check for violations. You are expected to wrap the entire DML operation in an if statement:

```
if (CustomObject__c.getSObjectType().getDescribe().isUpdateable()) {
  // Getting PMD Error: Validate CRUD permission before SOQL/DML operation
  update resultObjects;
  return resultObjects;
}
throw new DmlException('No permissions to update.');
```

Comment: I am checking for violations, if it's not updatable then it throws the exception.  It only seems to work on single objects.  I tried formatting my code to have the update inside an if and it's still showing the error for lists of objects.